# How to scrape data from a terminal and paste into Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to collect information from the terminal using column C as the source, but I don't know how to write the result in the following manner into Excel.

[image: What is needed]

This is the code I have so far:

```vb
Dim cell As Range
Dim Rs As String

For Each cell In sheet1.Range("C:C")
    Sess.putstring cell.Value, 1, 10, 3    'Query Value
    Sess.SendKeys "<ENTER>"
    Rs = Sess.screen.GetString(1, 11, 3)   'Result
Next cell
```

Comment: "collect information from the terminal" means what *exactly*?  Your question is not clear.

Comment: Hi Tim. I have reformulated the question, thank you!

Comment: How can we know what the return value from `Sess.screen.GetString(1, 11, 3)` looks like?  If you Debug.Print that and post it here it would help.

Comment: It's a string, and is always 3 alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```vb
Dim cell As Range
Dim Rs As String
  
For Each cell In sheet1.Range("C:C")
    Sess.putstring cell.Value, 1, 10, 3    'Query Value
    Sess.SendKeys "<ENTER>"
    Rs = Sess.screen.GetString(1, 11, 3)   'Result
    'append the result in the next empty cell in the same row
    cell.EntireRow.Cells(cell.EntireRow.Cells.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).value = Rs
Next cell
```